# Extract words from a string with specific conditions

Tags: python, regex

I'm extracting users getting tagged in messages, where the username contains digits so I need to extract words from a long string with the following conditions:

- it has to be 10 to 14 characters long
- it can start with a `@` but it is not necessary (this is the only special character allowed and if the word contains it, it has to be the first character)
- it can contain numbers and characters
- it can be only numbers, but it can't be only characters

Example:

```
str = "I have a pretty nice gaming experience with the user: @THYSSEN1145 and his brother THYSSEN1146. 
His username was first THY@SSEN1145, his brother's was 1234567891011. I played with them 123456789 times up until this point. "
```

Words that the regular expression should extract:

```
@THYSSEN1145
THYSSEN1146
1234567891011
```

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: Is `@` counted towards the char limit of 10-15?

Comment: yes @ it should be included

Comment: I thought of `(?!\B\w)(?!@?[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?:\B@|(?<!@)[a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,14}\b` that does not rely on whitespace boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<!\S)@?(?=[A-Za-z\d]{10,14}\b)[A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `@?` Match an optional `@`
- `(?=[A-Za-z\d]{10,14}\b)` Assert 10 - 14 word characters followed by a word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*` Match at least a digit in the ranges `A-Za-z\d`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NlPTBq/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)@?(?=[A-Za-z\d]{10,14}\b)[A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*"

s = ("I have a pretty nice gaming experience with the user: @THYSSEN1145 and his brother THYSSEN1146. \n"
            "His username was first THY@SSEN1145, his brother's was 1234567891011. I played with them 123456789 times up until this point.")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['@THYSSEN1145', 'THYSSEN1146', '1234567891011']
```

Comment: This regex will fails for long words containing digits.

Comment: @Cubix48 The question states `it has to be 10 to 14 characters long`

Comment: Thank you! but as Cubix48 mentioned if there is a digit longer than 14 characters, it will cut the last 14 characters of it, instead of excluding it

Comment: ie: "0120120121234567891011", it will include it as "090364451111111"

Comment: @Looz I see, I made a typo in the pattern. Now it does not allow a partial match. `(?<!\S)@?(?=[A-Za-z\d]{10,14}\b)[A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*` See https://regex101.com/r/NlPTBq/1 I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Looz That part `[A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*` is to prevent backtracking over the digit. First you match only the A-Za-z chars optionally, and then you make sure to match at least a single digit. Then when you have made sure that you have matched the digit, you optionally match all allowed characters in the last character class.